# after fork and the child process uses copy-on-write technique and how this realize

Tags: linux, kernel

in linux, when we fork(), and it isn't really copy all the resource to the child process. and it use copy-on-write technique for that. and what meaning of this?

for example:
if i called fork() as below:

```
pid=fork();
if(0==pid)
  {
     test(1);//something that i want to run
  }
else if (pid > 0)
{
     ;//some statement
}
else
{
  printf("error fork process\n");
}
```

and how to understand the copy-on-write on this example?

any advices would be much appreciated

Comment: Read [Fork (syscall)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fork_%28system_call%29) and [copy on write](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy_on_write) wikipages.

Comment: if i add execv("program", parameter) in son process, and what happened in system?

Comment: Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) then the relevant `man` pages of [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html), [execve(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html) etc...